# Trendline for data with two phases

Tags: curve-fitting, logarithm

I'd like to know how to fit a curve to a set of data that has two phases. For the below data I've tried using a third order polynomial, but I think that's overfitting the data and I've tried using logarithmic (correcting the data to positive numbers), but it seems like there should be a simpler way to get a hockey-stick(?)-like curve that does a better job of merging the two phases.

Is that possible?

[image: Graphed Data]